# Apple Watch: Storyboard localization will not work

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm currently working on an Apple Watch app which I'm trying to localize to Spanish.

The Base localization is in English and I'm trying to localize to Spanish.

Here's the problem:

1. The Storyboard for the Watch App has a file in it called Interface.strings(Spanish (United States)). I see the strings from the Storyboard in there just fine and they have their translations all set.
2. I have another file called Localizable.strings which is used for the actual code files themselves. This was generated by me using the NSLocalizedString function.

I have set both my phone and my watch to Spanish. When I build/run the app on the watch, it only translates the Strings from the Localizable.strings file but complete ignores the Storyboard localization files. This causes strings in buttons and the title bar to just not translate. Everything else, whatever was done in code, does translate though.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Running iOS 9 and watch OS 2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my localization was set to

es-US which is Spanish (United States). The Apple Watch only seems to have "es" for Spanish and it was trying to run as "es-US."

Anyway, what I did was create a new localization for my entire project just for "es" (not specific to any locale) based on my es-US. I then deleted my es-US localization.

Both iOS and watchOS register "es" just fine and any form of Spanish will now work just fine.

Comment: Exactly, I had the very same issue with "de-CH" : since Swiss-German did not work, I needed to change my localization to "de" for German-German :) - after that any Swiss-German language setting on iPhone or Watch would then translate to German as intended. It seems that localization only works for the default "big-country-languages" (such as "de", "es" or "fr") but localization does not work for smaller, more regional languages (such as "es-US" or "de-CH")...